# edit comments in front end

Tags: comments, comment-form

I build my custom comments template.
And i realised tht edit comment is being done in back-end ( dashbord).
Is there any way to enable edit comments in the front-end instead of in admin menu?
Would be possible to use the same form as i used for new comment?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to edit comments in the front end. Use this

For default edit comment link,

```
<?php edit_comment_link(); ?> 
          ( or ) 
<?php edit_comment_link(__('edit comment'), '<p>', '</p>'); ?>
```

Hook is, **apply_filters()** Calls '**edit_comment_link**' hook on the author email

**Let Me know Incase of any issues**

Comment: i dont understand. could you write quick example?
i use this function to enable the edit comment but when pressed, the back-end admin editor is being loaded.
but my aim is to use the same editor window at front end.

Comment: ok. I will check it and let you know. Some WordPress plugins available for forend comment editing. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ajax-edit-comments/